# Data validation with Entity

Tags: c#, entity

There are columns from the database. I added Required and MinValue to these columns as follows. How can I do this validation in Form1?
Thanks.

```
public partial class okuyucular
    {
        public int okuyucu_İD { get; set; }
        [Required]
       [MinLength(3,ErrorMessage ="hatalı isim girişi")]
        public string okuyucu_ad { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string okuyucu_soyad { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please add some more information about what kind of technology you are using. The validation attributes do not do anything on their own, they just denote what kind of validation is expected on these fields. To actually conduct the validation you need a special middleware, which would be different based on your technology stack.

Comment: Hello there
They told me that I can do this using the DataAnnotations class. I am using EF6 model from database in c # project. I really don't know how to do it. I could not see examples in Msdn Docs sources.

Comment: AFAIK, EF doesn't do any kind of validation. It assumes that the DB would do it. So you shouldn't need to validate the data that comes from the DB. It should have all the constraints. Now if you want to validate the data that you want to store in the DB, then yes, you need to do it yourself. But the question then would be: where do you get this data from? Because that's where you should validate it.

Comment: Disagreeing with @Morse, EF will throw an error on SaveChanges if you try to insert or update an entity with a null value for a property that has been flagged as required. If you want to validate on the form, I suggest you check out the [Control.Validating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=net-5.0) and [Control.Validated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validated?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Hello there
Here's what I want to do:
To validate the feeder entered from the TextBox in Form1 without registering it in the database. I want the user to give "no blank pass" without saving when the user enters blank data.
TextBoxes on Form1 are bound to BindingSource and Entity classes.
What do I have to do in this situation?

Comment: Hello there For TextBoxValidating, doing this for all TextBoxes in the project will cost code. I would like to handle this with Entity. How can I do this using DataAnnotations or IvalidateObject? How can I get if there is an error in Form1? –

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with DataAnnotations, I can do data validation more easily with FluentValidation. I use FluentValidation in my next projects.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31910134)